# Setting variable for execution both from web and from php CLI Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, php, cron, php-cli

So I have a web script that I need a little help with. While accessing the script from the web I use `faucet?id=1467` in the web address.

The code on the script then reads `$id = getiparam('id');` and everything works great.

What I am trying to do now is setup a cronjob that calls `php myscript.php` But I am having trouble passing the 1467 to it.

Ideally it would be  `php myscript.php 1467` and it runs like it should.

Ive searched and tried several different solutions but I can not modify them to work as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
env QUERY_STRING="id=1467" php myscript.php
```

Comment: tried that one already, and doesnt work, I get a PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getiparam() in myscript.php on line 16 which that line is the $id = getiparam('id'); line

Comment: I don't know PHP. Sounds like you have to figure out what modules/libraries get imported into the web environment, and somehow pick them up in the script environment.